# java xmx option not recognised

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, talend

I am using a BI data integration tool called Talend built over Eclipse using Java.

On launching a job it says

```
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
Unrecognized option: --Xmx1024M
```

ini file:

```
-vmargs
-Xms64m
-Xmx1536m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

ive a 4GB 32 bit windows pc. 2.85GB usable

Comment: could you update the post with the eclipse.ini file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only use one dash e.g.

```
java -Xmx1024m  ....
```

See [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#options) for more command-line option info.

Comment: in fact it gives the same error for even single dash. the ini files also have single dash in them.

Comment: sorry with one dash it doesnt give the error unless x is in miniscule. but at the eclipse terminal it gives this error.

Comment: What are you putting in the Eclipse terminal, and what error does it give you?

Comment: One gotcha is that if you copy the 'dash' from a Word document, it may *appear* to be the same dash chracter but is in fact a different character. Retype it from the keyboard and try that

Comment: @BrianAgnew Im trying to execute a tool built on Java and gives the error Could not create the Java virtual machine.
Unrecognized option: --Xmx1024M
id appreciate if you could tell me what could have gone wrong